# Technology behind PDFBuddy [dot] com?

Tags: php, pdf

pdfbuddy [dot] com is an online solution to upload your pdf files, edit (draw, highlight etc etc) and later save/download the modified files.

I am curious to know what could probably be the server-side solution they use?

When I draw something random and save the changes, the ajax request posted is, like:

```
 document[data]:{"pages":{"1":{"elements":[{"type":"PATH","family":"PATH","style":{"stroke_width":2,"stroke_color":"#000000"},"transform":{"x":"247.5","y":"173","scaleX":"1","scaleY":"1"},"content":{"data":"M64
 6 L64 9 L64 17 L64 29 L64 43 L64 56 L64 66 L66 74 L68 79 L71 82 L75 84
 L80 85 L86 85 L95 79 L102 67 L109 56 L114 42 L116 27 L117 17 L117 8
 L117 4 L115 0 L109 0 L102 1 L95 6 L89 11 L85 20 L80 31 L77 45 L74 59
 L71 75 L68 90 L65 99 L63 107 L59 113 L54 117 L48 121 L37 123 L27 124
 L18 124 L10 123 L6 118 L2 113 L0 103 L0 89 L7 72 L18 56 L26 48 L36 43
 L44 41 L52 44 L62 52 L71 62 L84 74 L95 82 L105 91 L115 96 L121 100
 L128 102 L133 102 L138 102 L143 99 L150 91 L153 83 L155 71 L156 59
 L154 45 L149 32 L141 23 L130 16 L121 13 L113 13 L104 14 L96 22 L88 33
 L80 48 L74 65 L69 84 L64 101 L61 114 L58 124 L56 131 L55 136 L54 139
 L53 141 L53 144 L53 147 L53 150 L54 153 L55 157 L56 160 L58 162 L61
 163 L66 163 L71 163 L80 160 L91 153 L103 139 L115 126 L123 115 L129
 107 L133 101 L135 99 L136 98 L136 97 L137 97 L140 97 L143 99 L147 102
 L151 104 L153 106 L154 108 L156 112 L158 116 L160 120 L162 125 L164
 129 L165 134 L167 137 L167 140 L168 142 L168 145 L169 147 L170 148
 L171 150 L172 151 L174 152 L175 152 L177 152 L180 152 L182 152 L184
 151 L185 150 L185 150"}}],"width":595,"height":841}}}
```

What exactly is those values in content->data? Which application on their server process this data and generate new pdf files?

Thank you!

Comment: [builtwith.com](http://builtwith.com/pdfbuddy.com)

Comment: I am more interested to know which application / package / programming module is being used to update pdf files based on the values posted via ajax call.

Comment: *What exactly is those values in content->data* - I would assume `M64 6` = *move to 64,6* and `L64 9` = *line to 64,9* etc.

Comment: Finally got to know that they are actually SVG data. http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp